# Pass a pointer to a C++ struct into Ada

Tags: c++, ada

I have a C++ structure in "MyData.h"

```
struct MyData
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

That I want to pass a pointer of it into an Ada call

```
#include "MyData.h"
extern "C" void ada_call(MyData* data);

void func()
{
    MyData* data = new MyData();
    ada_call(data);
}
```

How can I build an Ada function that will accept this?

Answer (score 2):

The solution has a couple steps to it.

You need to generate an Ada record for that struct. g++ has a [built in tool for doing this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Generating-Ada-Bindings-for-C-and-C_002b_002b-headers.html#Generating-Ada-Bindings-for-C-and-C_002b_002b-headers). Run:

```
g++ -c -fdump-ada-spec "MyData.h" -C
```

And you will get a mydata_h.ads which has a definition of a record that matches your struct. It should look like this:

```
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;

package MyData_h is

   type MyData is record
      a : aliased int;  -- MyData.h:3
      b : aliased int;  -- MyData.h:4
   end record;
   pragma Convention (C_Pass_By_Copy, MyData);  -- MyData.h:1

end MyData_h;
```

Once you have that, you need to write a procedure that takes it as a parameter. This procedure must have it passed as 'access', it must then be exported, so it is accessible from C.

data_function.ads:

```
with MyData_h;
use MyData_h;

package DATA_FUNCTION is
    procedure ADA_CALL ( DATA : access MyData_h.MyData );
    pragma Export(Convention=>C,Entity=>ADA_CALL,External_Name=>"ada_call");
end DataFunction;
```

data_function.adb

```
with MyData_h;
use MyData_h;
with Interfaces.C; use Interfaces.C;

package body DATA_FUNCTION is

    procedure ADA_CALL ( DATA : access MyData_h.MyData )
    begin
        DATA.a = 1;
        DATA.b = 2;
    end ADA_CALL;
end DATA_FUNCTION;
```

Comment: The `C_Pass_By_Copy` serves no purpose here, as far as I can tell.

Comment: That is part of the codegen that comes out of g++, I didn't control that.

Comment: Another good reference for [Ada/C interaction](http://flyx.org/2012/06/13/adabindings1/).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364380/passing-an-array-allocated-from-a-c-routine-to-ada) is also related

Comment: @ajb, I think the point is that the translation process doesn’t know how the record declaration would be used. You would have thought that GNAT (being part of GCC) wouldn’t need this convention, plain C would do. I can see that other compilers might.

Comment: I missed that the file was auto-generated--sorry.